# Spring Cloud Data Flow YARN: fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm running spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn-dist-1.2.0.RELEASE server in docker cloudera container with SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904-el6.parcel and hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.11.1.

I have imported applications:

```
app import --uri http://bitly/Bacon-RELEASE-stream-applications-kafka-10-maven
```

and have the following stream:

```
stream create foo --definition "triggertask --uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:timestamp-task:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT --fixed-delay=5 | task-launcher-yarn" --deploy
```

When I deploy this stream to server, it fails with exception:

```
2017-12-04 17:24:52,273 ERROR main o.s.b.SpringApplication:815 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bindingService' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService]: Factory method 'bindingService' threw exception; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.task.launcher.yarn.sink.kafka.TaskLauncherYarnSinkKafka10Application.main(TaskLauncherYarnSinkKafka10Application.java:29) [classes!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [task-launcher-yarn-sink-kafka-10-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [task-launcher-yarn-sink-kafka-10-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [task-launcher-yarn-sink-kafka-10-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [task-launcher-yarn-sink-kafka-10-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService]: Factory method 'bindingService' threw exception; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:102) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:45) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:423) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(ConfigurationImpl.java:575) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.CustomValidatorBean.afterPropertiesSet(CustomValidatorBean.java:71) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.(BindingService.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration.bindingService(BindingServiceConfiguration.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51fb52d5.CGLIB$bindingService$4() ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51fb52d5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa72af57.invoke() ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51fb52d5.bindingService() ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:98) ~[hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar!/:5.3.4.Final]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed via: [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-yarn#4](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-yarn/pull/4).

Please try the local-build of the application and let us know if you see any other anomalies. Thanks for reporting it!